# Highcharts: update chart when data actualized

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, updates

I am using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) and I would like [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-scatter-draggable/dark-unica) chart to update each second. This is what I have now: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/etcbevp2/4/)

I have timer `window.setInterval(updateChart, 1000);` and it works properly actualizing data each second.

But I have no idea how to actualize the view. **It is important that I don't want to draw chart again and again each second.** I only want to shift points and add new ones. Do anyone know how to do that?

Comment: have you looked at the Highcharts demo that does this?  http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

Comment: I've seen this but I need this 3D version to update. But @Mark has already answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the the series.addPoint [method](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint).

Your `updateChart` function becomes:

```
function updateChart()
{
    for (var source = 1; source <=3; source++)
    {
                var point = [
                23,
                Math.floor((Math.random() * 10*source) + 5+source*2),
                source
            ];
        Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].addPoint(point, false, true); // add the point, don't redraw and shift off a point
    }
    Highcharts.charts[0].redraw(); // 3 points added, now redraw

}
```

Update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/etcbevp2/5/).